# Pt to sp conversion issue

Tags: android, photoshop

I have a photoshop maket with 300ppi and 1080 x 1920 pixels size.

Our designer uses 10pt font size. I converted it to 23sp and used in my app.
I tested on a Nexus 5 emulator (1080 x 1920 and ~445 ppi) and text much more bigger than on maket.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use a scaleable type of dp/sp. This repo is a very nice way to support mutliple screens without actually writing for each screen size. https://github.com/intuit/sdp/tree/master/sdp-android/src/main/res

All you have to do to use it if for example you are in an xml file, do this like so:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
```

This effectively makes the widget you set the width to be consistent on all device screens. I hope this helps.